# How to discretize a thin prism

Tags: mesh, computational-geometry

I have a very thin prism that I want to discretize using DiscretizeRegion:

```
pts={{100.,-50.,151.975},{2064.,-50.,151.975},{100.,2076.,151.975},{100.,-50.,152.025},{2064.,-50.,152.025},{100.,2076.,152.025}};
sail=Prism[pts];
DiscretizeRegion[sail]
```

but this results in the error "DiscretizeRegion: A non-degenerate region is expected at position 1 of..."

This appears to be a numerical issue because if I increase the thickness of the sail, the problem goes away.  Is there a way to coax Mathematica into performing the discretization?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
pts = {{100., -50., 151.975}, {2064., -50., 151.975}, {100., 2076., 
    151.975}, {100., -50., 152.025}, {2064., -50., 152.025}, {100., 
    2076., 152.025}};

sail = Prism[pts];

bdgh = BoundaryDiscretizeRegion[Rationalize[sail], 
  MaxCellMeasure -> {1 -> 100}]

HighlightMesh[bdgh, 1]
```

---

[image]

Comment: These are pictures, not Meshes.

Comment: The idea of using Rationalize is great!  Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

- `BoundaryDiscretizeGraphics`

```
bdg = BoundaryDiscretizeGraphics[sail]
HighlightMesh[bdg, 1, BoxRatios -> 1, Axes -> True]
```

[image]